# Chi-square tests for different groups in a R dataframe

Tags: r, testing, dplyr, chi-squared

I have a huge dataframe with the following basic structure:

```
data <- data.frame(species = factor(c(rep("species1", 4), rep("species2", 4), rep("species3", 4))),
                 trap = c(rep(c("A","B","C","D"), 3)),
                 count=c(6,3,7,9,5,3,6,6,5,8,1,3))
data
```

I want simultaneously chi-square tests for the species counting data between the four traps for each individually species, but not between them. It could be solved with the following code for each individually species, but because of my huge original dataframe it is not a suitable solution for me.

```
chi_species1 <- xtabs(count~trap, data, 
                       subset = species=="species1")
chi_species1
chisq.test(chi_species1)
```

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**base**

```r
df <- data.frame(species = factor(c(rep("species1", 4), rep("species2", 4), rep("species3", 4))),
                   trap = c(rep(c("A","B","C","D"), 3)),
                   count=c(6,3,7,9,5,3,6,6,5,8,1,3))
df
#>     species trap count
#> 1  species1    A     6
#> 2  species1    B     3
#> 3  species1    C     7
#> 4  species1    D     9
#> 5  species2    A     5
#> 6  species2    B     3
#> 7  species2    C     6
#> 8  species2    D     6
#> 9  species3    A     5
#> 10 species3    B     8
#> 11 species3    C     1
#> 12 species3    D     3

species <- unique(df$species)

chi_species <- lapply(species, function(x) xtabs(count~trap, df, 
                      subset = species== x))

chi_species <- setNames(chi_species, species)

lapply(chi_species, chisq.test)

#> $species1
#> 
#>  Chi-squared test for given probabilities
#> 
#> data:  X[[i]]
#> X-squared = 3, df = 3, p-value = 0.3916
#> 
#> 
#> $species2
#> 
#>  Chi-squared test for given probabilities
#> 
#> data:  X[[i]]
#> X-squared = 1.2, df = 3, p-value = 0.753
#> 
#> 
#> $species3
#> 
#>  Chi-squared test for given probabilities
#> 
#> data:  X[[i]]
#> X-squared = 6.2941, df = 3, p-value = 0.09815
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**tidyverse**

```
df %>% 
  group_by(species, trap) %>% 
  summarise(count = sum(count)) %>% 
  summarise(pvalue= chisq.test(count)$p.value) 

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  species  pvalue
  <fct>     <dbl>
1 species1 0.392 
2 species2 0.753 
3 species3 0.0981
```

Comment: Thank you :-) Can you tell me why the p values with your method are different to them in Quinten's method?

Comment: Quinten calculations use 
`tmp <- df %>% filter(species == "species1")`
`chisq.test(x = tmp$count, y = tmp$trap)`
I have implemented the description of your example

Comment: I also added the `tidyverse` calculation code to the example

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(species) %>% 
  summarise(pvalue= chisq.test(count, trap)$p.value)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  species  pvalue
  <fct>     <dbl>
1 species1  0.213
2 species2  0.238
3 species3  0.213
```